# Why is my program not printing all of the possibilities

Tags: python

I am making a program that shows you all of the possible combinations of a password according to if it has numbers if it has letters if it has symbols and how long it is. At the start of where it prints out the possibilities, it says that there are 10000 possibilities (when there are only actually 1000) according to an equation but at the end of the program it says there were only 715

```
import itertools
loop = True
count = 0
a = 1
input("Welcome to the Password Possibilities Test")
input("This test will tell you how many possible")
input("combinations a password can have")
input("*all answers must start with an uppercase*")
num_length = 0
alpha_length = 0
sym_length = 0
num = input("So lets start does your password have numbers?\n")
alpha = input("Does it have letters?\n")
sym = input("Does it have symbols?\n")
long = input("Do you know how long the password is?\n")

possibilities = []

if long == "Yes":
    length = input("How long is the password?\n")
elif long == "No":
    print("Then we will go off of the average password length which is 8\n")
    length = 8

if num == "Yes":
    num_length = 10
    possibilities.append(0)
    possibilities.append(1)
    possibilities.append(2)
    possibilities.append(3)
    possibilities.append(4)
    possibilities.append(5)
    possibilities.append(6)
    possibilities.append(7)
    possibilities.append(8)
    possibilities.append(9)

else:
    num_length = 0

if alpha == "Yes":
    alpha_length = 52
    possibilities.append("a")
    possibilities.append("b")
    possibilities.append("c")
    possibilities.append("d")
    possibilities.append("e")
    possibilities.append("f")
    possibilities.append("g")
    possibilities.append("h")
    possibilities.append("i")
    possibilities.append("j")
    possibilities.append("k")
    possibilities.append("l")
    possibilities.append("m")
    possibilities.append("n")
    possibilities.append("o")
    possibilities.append("p")
    possibilities.append("q")
    possibilities.append("r")
    possibilities.append("s")
    possibilities.append("t")
    possibilities.append("u")
    possibilities.append("v")
    possibilities.append("w")
    possibilities.append("x")
    possibilities.append("y")
    possibilities.append("z")
    possibilities.append("A")
    possibilities.append("B")
    possibilities.append("C")
    possibilities.append("D")
    possibilities.append("E")
    possibilities.append("F")
    possibilities.append("G")
    possibilities.append("H")
    possibilities.append("I")
    possibilities.append("J")
    possibilities.append("K")
    possibilities.append("L")
    possibilities.append("M")
    possibilities.append("N")
    possibilities.append("O")
    possibilities.append("P")
    possibilities.append("Q")
    possibilities.append("R")
    possibilities.append("S")
    possibilities.append("T")
    possibilities.append("U")
    possibilities.append("V")
    possibilities.append("W")
    possibilities.append("X")
    possibilities.append("Y")
    possibilities.append("Z")
else:
    alpha_length = 0

if sym == "Yes":
    sym_length = 32
    possibilities.append("!")
    possibilities.append("@")
    possibilities.append("#")
    possibilities.append("$")
    possibilities.append("%")
    possibilities.append("^")
    possibilities.append("&")
    possibilities.append("*")
    possibilities.append("(")
    possibilities.append(")")
    possibilities.append("_")
    possibilities.append("+")
    possibilities.append("{")
    possibilities.append("}")
    possibilities.append("|")
    possibilities.append(":")
    possibilities.append("\\")
    possibilities.append("?")
    possibilities.append(">")
    possibilities.append("<")
    possibilities.append("~")
    possibilities.append("`")
    possibilities.append("[")
    possibilities.append("]")
    possibilities.append("\"")
    possibilities.append(";")
    possibilities.append("'")
    possibilities.append("/")
    possibilities.append(".")
    possibilities.append(",")
    possibilities.append("`")
else:
    sym_length = 0

num_length = int(num_length)
alpha_length = int(alpha_length)
sym_length = int(sym_length)
length = int(length)



calc = num_length + alpha_length + sym_length
final = pow(calc,length)
print("This password has ",final, "possibilities")
input("Click the ENTER key to view all of the combonations")
for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(possibilities,length):
    print(i)
    count +=1
print("This password has ",count, "possibilities")
exit = input("Would you like to exit?\n")
if exit == "Yes":
    pass
elif exit == "No":
    while loop == True:
        a = 1
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: tl:dr, look into itertools

Comment: When you're counting the possibilities when printing you're counting ('a','b') as the same as ('b','a') in the itertools function, so only counting them once.